# JavaFX - clearing my ComboBox set's off my listener, how do I fix this?

Tags: java, combobox, listener, javafx-8

I have a problem as you can see in the code below, to where when I change the value in my cbGameType ComboBox it clears the cbPlayerCount ComboBox which sets off the cbPlayerCount listener and throws an error. This results in the ComboBox being unresponsive and not changing the cbGameType comboBox Value until another value is set. After another value is set the program begins working properly again, how would I fix this?

Edit: By the way, the specific code that throws this is below:

```
cbPlayerCount.getItems().clear();
```

Edit: And the whole listener is here

```
// Sets additional player for specific game type
cbGameType.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
    cbPlayerCount.getItems().clear();
    if (!cbGameType.getValue().equals("Texas Hold 'Em")) {
        cbPlayerCount.getItems().addAll(olPlayerCount.subList(0, 6));
        cbPlayerCount.setValue(olPlayerCount.get(5));
    } else {
        cbPlayerCount.getItems().addAll(olPlayerCount.subList(1, 5));
        cbPlayerCount.setValue(olPlayerCount.get(1));
    }
});
```

Edit: And the code for the cbPlayerCount ComboBox listener that is being triggered upon the clearing of the comboBox is below. I am assuming that what is happening is that it's trying the else statement to set the new value but it hasn't had a value set yet.

```
    // Set AI count specifically based on the number of players/game
cbPlayerCount.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
    cbAICount.getItems().clear();
    if (cbGameType.getValue().equals("Texas Hold 'Em")) {
        if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("2 Players")) {
            cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 1));
            cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(0));
        } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("3 Players")) {
            cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 2));
            cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(1));
        } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("4 Players")) {
            cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 3));
            cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(2));
        } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("5 Players")) {
            cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 4));
            cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(3));
        } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("6 Players")) {
            cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 5));
            cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(4));
        }
    } else {
        if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("1 Player") ||
                cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("2 Players")) {
            cbAICount.setVisible(false);
        } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("3 Players")) {
            cbAICount.setVisible(true);
            cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 1));
            cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(0));
        } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("4 Players")) {
            cbAICount.setVisible(true);
            cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 2));
            cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(1));
        } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("5 Players")) {
            cbAICount.setVisible(true);
            cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 3));
            cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(2));
        } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("6 Players")) {
            cbAICount.setVisible(true);
            cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 4));
            cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(3));
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the rest of the code

```
Stage newGameStage = new Stage();
    VBox pane = new VBox(5);

    // Label and ComboBox for gameType selection
    BorderPane gameTypePane = new BorderPane();
    ComboBox<String> cbGameType = new ComboBox<>();
    cbGameType.setPrefWidth(160);
    cbGameType.getItems().addAll("Texas Hold 'Em", "7-Card Stud",
        "Omaha", "5-Card Draw", "High/Low Chicago", "Follow the Queen",
        "BlackJack");
    cbGameType.setValue("Texas Hold 'Em");
    Label lbGameType = new Label("Game Type:");
    lbGameType.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    gameTypePane.setLeft(lbGameType);
    gameTypePane.setRight(cbGameType);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(cbGameType, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    pane.getChildren().add(gameTypePane);

    // Label and ComboBox for number of Players
    BorderPane playerCountPane = new BorderPane();
    ObservableList<String> olPlayerCount =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList( "1 Player", "2 Players",
            "3 Players", "4 Players", "5 Players", "6 Players");
    ComboBox<String> cbPlayerCount = new ComboBox<>();
    cbPlayerCount.getItems().addAll(olPlayerCount.subList(1, 6));
    cbPlayerCount.setValue(olPlayerCount.get(5));
    Label lbPlayerCount = new Label("Select Players");
    lbPlayerCount.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    playerCountPane.setLeft(lbPlayerCount);
    playerCountPane.setRight(cbPlayerCount);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(cbPlayerCount, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    pane.getChildren().add(playerCountPane);

    // Label and ComboBox for selecting the number of AI Players
    BorderPane aiCountPane = new BorderPane();
    ObservableList<String> olAI = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "1 AI", "2 AI", "3 AI",
            "4 AI", "5 AI");
    ComboBox<String> cbAICount = new ComboBox<>();
    cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 5));
    cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(4));
    Label lbAICount = new Label("How many AI: ");
    lbAICount.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    aiCountPane.setLeft(lbAICount);
    aiCountPane.setRight(cbAICount);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(cbAICount, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    pane.getChildren().add(aiCountPane);

    // Sets additional player for specific game type
    cbGameType.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
        cbPlayerCount.getItems().clear();
        if (!cbGameType.getValue().equals("Texas Hold 'Em")) {
            cbPlayerCount.getItems().addAll(olPlayerCount.subList(0, 6));
            cbPlayerCount.setValue(olPlayerCount.get(5));
        } else {
            cbPlayerCount.getItems().addAll(olPlayerCount.subList(1, 5));
            cbPlayerCount.setValue(olPlayerCount.get(1));
        }
    });

    // Set AI count specifically based on the number of players/game
    cbPlayerCount.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
        cbAICount.getItems().clear();
        if (cbGameType.getValue().equals("Texas Hold 'Em")) {
            if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("2 Players")) {
                cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 1));
                cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(0));
            } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("3 Players")) {
                cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 2));
                cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(1));
            } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("4 Players")) {
                cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 3));
                cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(2));
            } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("5 Players")) {
                cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 4));
                cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(3));
            } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("6 Players")) {
                cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 5));
                cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(4));
            }
        } else {
            if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("1 Player") ||
                    cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("2 Players")) {
                cbAICount.setVisible(false);
            } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("3 Players")) {
                cbAICount.setVisible(true);
                cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 1));
                cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(0));
            } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("4 Players")) {
                cbAICount.setVisible(true);
                cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 2));
                cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(1));
            } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("5 Players")) {
                cbAICount.setVisible(true);
                cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 3));
                cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(2));
            } else if (cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("6 Players")) {
                cbAICount.setVisible(true);
                cbAICount.getItems().addAll(olAI.subList(0, 4));
                cbAICount.setValue(olAI.get(3));
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the error it throws upon the first change of the value in the cbGameType ComboBox

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$newGame$2(Main.java:200)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$5/624953014.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:339)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:167)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.updateValue(ComboBox.java:449)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.access$300(ComboBox.java:164)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$6.changed(ComboBox.java:434)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:347)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel$1.invalidated(ComboBox.java:481)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel$2.onChanged(ComboBox.java:504)
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:315)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:72)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.clear(ObservableListWrapper.java:155)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$newGame$1(Main.java:169)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$4/1075013361.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:339)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:167)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.updateValue(ComboBox.java:449)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.access$300(ComboBox.java:164)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$6.changed(ComboBox.java:434)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:347)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel$1.invalidated(ComboBox.java:481)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(SingleSelectionModel.java:215)
at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.select(SingleSelectionModel.java:149)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$9.invalidated(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:594)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:339)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:341)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:309)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListCellBehavior.simpleSelect(ListCellBehavior.java:268)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListCellBehavior.doSelect(ListCellBehavior.java:208)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListCellBehavior.mousePressed(ListCellBehavior.java:127)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the combo box is cleared, the `value` property is set to `null`. So statements like `cbPlayerCount.getValue().equals("2 Players")` will throw a Null Pointer Exception (attempting to invoke the `equals(...)` method on a null reference).

You have a couple of options depending on the logic you want to implement. You could use [`Objects.equals(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) for your comparison, which would do an appropriate null check on each argument:

```
if (Objects.equals(cbPlayerCount.getValue(), "2 Players")) {
    //...
}
```

Or you could just wrap the contents of your listener in

```
if (cbPlayerCount.getValue() != null) {
  //...
}
```

With the second option, it may be worth thinking about whether or not there is some change you'd want to make to the other combo boxes if no value is really selected.

Answer (score 0):

James_D, I set a breakpoint in my debugger and realized what you were saying. Basically upon clearing the cbPlayerCount it was jumping to the cbPlayerCount listener from the cbGameType listener. It was then trying to perform the 'getvalue.equals()' method on the cbPlayerCount which as you pointed out was null. After that it would jump back to the last line in the cbGameType listener and continue adding and setting the value. So in the end setting a condition for null as you stated above was all I needed to fix the issue.